# two equal width div in html

Tags: css, html

I have a page that contain the following code

```
<html>
  <body>
 <div class="op">.....content.......</div>
 <div class="op">.....content.......</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i am going to print this page in a4 sheet , but when i print this it is not adjusted equally with paper size .Each div have same content ,they just repeating .I need to make them fit in to the paper .So that i can cut the paper by 2, so that they both have same width .Please help

Comment: What CSS did you use?

Comment: More information please. Show your CSS "op" class styles and what exactly the content you're trying to display is. Also it's somewhat unclear what you're saying.. You want to print a piece of paper and have one div be printed on the top half of the paper and one on the bottom, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its aboute your printer setting! Not about css or html. you must set your printer setting to fit the code for paper size. If you want print html final page (result of your code) maybe you code take apart with setting `width:50%` .i offering you to check your printer setting or system perinting setting for html pages.

Answer (score 2):

Show Your CSS 
After addin CSS ,place the first div width 50% and 2nd also 50% and make them both float left.

For Example:

```
          .op
           {
            float:left;
             width:50%;
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use separate stylesheet for print styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print, handheld" href="foo.css">
```

So, you can add styles which affect only for printing.